# Recalbox can run psp in Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: recalbox

i recently start a project and i am building my own arcade cabinet with raspberry pi, a arcade kit with [umolding](https://omniretro.com/productos-arcade/accesorios/molding/u-molding-16mm/) and stickers.

I want emulate some psp games but i dont know if i can with Recalbox with Raspberry Pi 3.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Recalbox can run the psp emulator on the Raspberry Pi 3.

Some games may be slow on a Pi3.

https://github.com/recalbox/recalbox-os/wiki/Board-Compatibility-(EN)